# How to find replacements for Dashboard widgets in macOS Notficiation Center

Tags: mojave, catalina, widgets, macos

I have been hesitating "upgrading" to macOS Catalina from Mojave because of its loss of the Dashboard.  I know that the Notification Center's "Today" view is supposed to replace the functionality of the Dashboard, and I'm willing to adapt to a new workflow if it's possible to recreate it in the newer OS version, but thus far I haven't found the same set of widgets that I use in the Dashboard.

Notification Center seems to have a different set of working assumptions than Dashboard.  That is, instead of installing widgets, you have to install an application that supports a Notification Center extension.  Apps produced these days are mostly trying to grab your attention (hence "Notification" Center) rather than providing useful functions.

Specifically, there are a couple of dictionaries, including the built-in dictionary app and a 3rd party foreign language dictionary, that I frequently use in the Dashboard.  There is also a general-purpose web clipper tool that you can use to create a new widget out of a website.

Is there:

1. Some secret rich repository of Notification Center widgets I don't know about where I might find a replacement for the dictionaries I use?
2. A way to search the Apple App Store for applications that offer widgets?
3. Some magic I can do with Script Editor to expose a widget from a current app like the macOS Dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, I've updated to macOS Catalina now.  The Notification center now has an "App Store" button that takes you to Apple's AppStore, where there is a section for Notification Center Widgets.  Although the selection is somewhat limited, it's nice to see a small collection of widgets.
[image]

Although there is no widget to replace the dictionaries I described in the original post, it is not hard to use ⌘-Space to quickly get Apple's Dictionary App.  It is pretty straightforward to add various foreign language dictionaries to that application.

All in all, it has been possible to replace the features I liked in the discontinued Dashboard with Notification Center Widgets and other applications.

Comment: The collection is very limited and most useful apps are not free. Basically we need to pay extra for what used to get out of the box with the OS X.